# Cobrança de taxa de entrega: às vezes funciona e as vezes não

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário de entrega que utiliza um arquivo (form.js) onde contem os dados de cobrança por CEP, até ai tudo bem, minha dúvida é, porque as vezes ele cobra e depois não cobra, sendo o mesmo CEP?
Exemplo: Tem dia que o CEP 20240-200 ele reconhece e cobra R$ 4,30 e no outro não! Pior, as vezes tem mais de um pedido para o mesmo CEP e ele NO MESMO DIA cobra para um e não cobra para outro pedido, como isso pode acontecer????

Segue o CODIGO completo desse arquivo:

```
 //aqui eu pego o cep
var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;

//verifica se deve incrementar ou não
if(cep == "20040-010" || cep == "20071-002" || cep == "20090-910" || cep == "20210-010" || cep == "20080-102" || cep == "20230-130" || cep == "20081-250" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20090-030" || cep == "20211-340" || cep == "20211-351" || cep == "20221-240" || cep == "20221-250" || cep == "20230-010" || cep == "20230-011" || cep == "20230-025" || cep == "20230-150" || cep == "20230-160" || cep == "20230-240" || cep == "20231-016" || cep == "20231-030" || cep == "20231-031" || cep == "20231-050" || cep == "20211-005" || cep == "20231-085" || cep == "20230-014" || cep == "20231-004" || cep == "20021-180" || cep == "20240-180" || cep == "20240-051" || cep == "20211-010" || cep == "20230-170" || cep == "20230-024" || cep == "20240-050" || cep == "20230-050" || cep == "20231-006" || cep == "20090-010" || cep == "20230-901" || cep == "20040-051" || cep == "20241-080" || cep == "20221-901" || cep == "20051-011" || cep == "20021-190" || cep == "20240-200" || cep == "20230-170" || cep == "20231-015" || cep == "20211-350" || cep == "20231-020" || cep == "20061-030"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 4 no valor final
    taxa = 4.30;


    //verifica se deve incrementar ou não
}if(cep == "20241-220" || cep == "22210-015" || cep == "22220-000" || cep == "20241-160" || cep == "20021-040" || cep == "20241-150" || cep == "22210-010" || cep == "22211-230" || cep == "22220-000" || cep == "22220-070" || cep == "22221-060" || cep == "22211-200" || cep == "22221-020" || cep == "20241-180" || cep == "20240-200"){

        //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 5.5 no valor final
    taxa = 6.0;


}if(cep == "20050-091" || cep == "20060-050" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20080-003" || cep == "20081-000" || cep == "20081-050" || cep == "20090-000" || cep == "20090-003" || cep == "20231-092" || cep == "24938-600" || cep == "20051-002" || cep == "20090-050" || cep == "20231-046" || cep == "20231-047" || cep == "20231-048" || cep == "20090-001" || cep == "20231-093" || cep == "20051-011" || cep == "20060-010" || cep == "20050-002"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3.5 no valor final
    taxa = 3.8;


}if(cep == "20031-170" || cep == "20040-004" || cep == "20040-902" | cep == "20021-360" || cep == "20040-020" || cep == "20040-908" || cep == "20071-000" || cep == "20230-070" || cep == "20071-004" || cep == "20040-009" || cep == "20230-060"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 3 no valor final
    taxa = 3.30;

}if(cep == "20010-010" || cep == "20020-906" || cep == "20031-908" || cep == "20031-917" || cep == "20040-001" || cep == "20040-006" || cep == "20050-090" || cep == "20070-022" || cep == "20031-909" || cep == "20031-904" || cep == "20021-390" || cep == "20031-919" || cep == "20031-912" || cep == "20031-905" || cep == "20050-060" || cep == "20031-901" || cep == "20031-924" || cep == "20051-040" || cep == "20031-901" || cep == "20003-191" || cep == "20241-110" || cep == "20050-030"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 2.5 no valor final
    taxa = 2.80;


}if(cep == "20010-020" || cep == "20011-020" || cep == "20011-030" || cep == "20011-040" || cep == "20011-901" || cep == "20020-000" || cep == "20010-170" || cep == "20011-000" || cep == "20021-260" || cep == "20021-350" || cep == "20031-040" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-130" || cep == "20031-204" || cep == "20021-245" || cep == "20040-002" || cep == "21335-253" || cep == "20040-031" || cep == "20030-041" || cep == "20040-000" || cep == "20004-002" || cep == "20040-003" || cep == "20040-007" || cep == "20011-010"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.7 no valor final
    taxa = 2.00;


}if(cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-001" || cep == "20031-000" || cep == "20031-003" || cep == "20031-010" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-141" || cep == "20031-143" || cep == "20031-005" || cep == "20031-001" || cep == "20020-903" || cep == "20031-144" || cep == "20030-080" || cep == "20031-142" || cep == "20031-120" || cep == "20031-007" || cep == "20010-009" || cep == "20031-913" || cep == "20021-370" || cep == "24220-280"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
    taxa = 1.50;


}if(cep == "20020-010" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20021-060" || cep == "20021-120" || cep == "20021-900" || cep == "20021-903" || cep == "20030-002" || cep == "20030-015" || cep == "20030-013" || cep == "20030-020" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20030-060" || cep == "20030-070" || cep == "20030-120" || cep == "20002-080" || cep == "20003-021" || cep == "20030-905" || cep == "20030-015"){

    //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
    taxa = 1.00;

}

total += taxa;      

if(taxa != 0){
    //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
    document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$ " + taxa;
}
```

Desde já agredeço e MUITO a atenção de todos!!

Comment: Alessandro será muito dificil que alguém possa olhar para todo esse código. Podes tentar isolar o pedaço que pode estar a dar-te problemas e descrever melhor o problema em si?

Comment: Oi Sergio, a parte do CEP é essa:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro algumas melhorias nesse código:

- Você possui vários CEPs para aplicar uma mesma taxa, agrupe esses CEPs em uma estrutura de dados, de forma que fique mais simples de compreender o código e mais simples de manipulá-los, sugiro um array ou um map nesse caso.
- Você possui vários **IFs** seguidos sem o uso do **ELSE**. Nesse caso você está perdendo performance, ou até mesmo pode ter um erro de lógica aí, dado que por mais que seja aplicada a taxa de `4.30` que está no primeiro **IF**, o fluxo do seu algoritmo ainda passará verificando em **TODOS** os outros `IFs`.
- No seu quarto `if` tem o seguinte trecho de código: `cep == "20040-902" | cep == "20021-360"`. Nesse caso você está utilizando um [operador bit a bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_bit_a_bit), onde esse trata seus operandos como um conjunto de 32 bits e não o dado como um todo, embora não faça muita diferença no seu caso dado que serão retornados apenas `1` ou `0` e Javascript traduz esses números para `true` ou `false`, acredito que ele não era para estar ai, mais detalhes [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Espero ter ajudado =)

Código com as minhas sugestões:

```
    var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;
    var taxa = 0;

    var cepRateMap = (function() {
        var map = new Map();

        map.set(4.30, [
            "20040-010", "20071-002", "20090-910", "20210-010", "20080-102",
            "20230-130", "20081-250", "20090-030", "20090-030", "20211-340",
            "20211-351", "20221-240", "20221-250", "20230-010", "20230-011",
            "20230-025", "20230-150", "20230-160", "20230-240", "20231-016",
            "20231-030", "20231-031", "20231-050", "20211-005", "20231-085",
            "20230-014", "20231-004", "20021-180", "20240-180", "20240-051",
            "20211-010", "20230-170", "20230-024", "20240-050", "20230-050",
            "20231-006", "20090-010", "20230-901", "20040-051", "20241-080",
            "20221-901", "20051-011", "20021-190", "20240-200", "20230-170",
            "20231-015", "20211-350", "20231-020", "20061-030"
        ]);
        map.set(6.0, [
            "20241-220", "22210-015", "22220-000", "20241-160", "20021-040",
            "20241-150", "22210-010", "22211-230", "22220-000", "22220-070",
            "22221-060", "22211-200", "22221-020", "20241-180", "20240-200"
        ]);
        map.set(3.8, [
            "20050-091", "20060-050", "20071-000", "20080-003", "20081-000",
            "20081-050", "20090-000", "20090-003", "20231-092", "24938-600",
            "20051-002", "20090-050", "20231-046", "20231-047", "20231-048",
            "20090-001", "20231-093", "20051-011", "20060-010", "20050-002"
        ]);
        map.set(3.3, [
            "20031-170", "20040-004", "20040-902", "20021-360", "20040-020",
            "20040-908", "20071-000", "20230-070", "20071-004", "20040-009",
            "20230-060"
        ]);
        map.set(2.8, [
            "20010-010", "20020-906", "20031-908", "20031-917", "20040-001",
            "20040-006", "20050-090", "20070-022", "20031-909", "20031-904",
            "20021-390", "20031-919", "20031-912", "20031-905", "20050-060",
            "20031-901", "20031-924", "20051-040", "20031-901", "20003-191",
            "20241-110", "20050-030"
        ]);
        map.set(2.0, [
            "20010-020", "20011-020", "20011-030", "20011-040", "20011-901",
            "20020-000", "20010-170", "20011-000", "20021-260", "20021-350",
            "20031-040", "20031-050", "20031-130", "20031-204", "20021-245",
            "20040-002", "21335-253", "20040-031", "20030-041", "20040-000",
            "20004-002", "20040-003", "20040-007", "20011-010"
        ]);
        map.set(1.5, [
            "20010-090", "20020-100", "20021-130", "20021-315", "20030-001",
            "20031-000", "20031-003", "20031-010", "20031-050", "20031-141",
            "20031-143", "20031-005", "20031-001", "20020-903", "20031-144",
            "20030-080", "20031-142", "20031-120", "20031-007", "20010-009",
            "20031-913", "20021-370", "24220-280"
        ]);
        map.set(1.0, [
            "20020-010", "20020-040", "20020-080", "20021-060", "20021-120",
            "20021-900", "20021-903", "20030-002", "20030-015", "20030-013",
            "20030-020", "20030-021", "20030-060", "20030-070", "20030-120",
            "20002-080", "20003-021", "20030-905", "20030-015"
        ]);

        return map;
    }());

    cepRateMap.forEach(function(values, key) {
        if (values.indexOf(cep) !== -1) {
            taxa = key;
        }
    });

    total += taxa;

    if (taxa != 0) {
        var elementRate = document.getElementById("idTaxa");
        elementRate.innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$ " + taxa;
    }
```

Comment: Pedro Muitoooooooo obrigado!!

Comment: Pedro, pintou um problema, não sei pq agora no e-mail não aparece mais a informação da taxa! `$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];` no formulário do site aparece a taxa (`<tr>
    <td>Taxa de Entrega:</td>
    <td><span id="idTaxa"></span></td>
  </tr>`, mas no e-mail que é processado pelo arquivo mail.php ele não está mais lendo, não envia a informação. Será que é algo nesse parte do código do java? `var taxa = 0;
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
var total = 0.00;
`